# Why isn't my UILongPressGestureRecognizer working?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have the following code and my long press is not working the way it should. Can anybody figure out why it isn't working?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "myButton:")
    longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
    myButton.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
}

@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func myButton(longPress: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if longPress.state != .Began {

        presentAlertController()

        return
    }
}
```

This error comes up when i Hold down on the button

```
2016-01-09 00:41:28.785 longPressTest[1870:551106] Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x144d6a500>  on <longPressTest.ViewController: 0x144e3a450> which is already presenting <UIAlertController: 0x144e59d80>
2016-01-09 00:41:28.903 longPressTest[1870:551106] Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UIAlertController: 0x144d6a500>)
2016-01-09 00:41:28.905 longPressTest[1870:551106] Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x144e54bb0>  on <longPressTest.ViewController: 0x144e3a450> which is already presenting <UIAlertController: 0x144e59d80>
Cancel
```

Comment: What does “not working the way it should” mean? How is it working, and how should it be working?

Comment: @ rob mayor I want to hold the long gesture for 0.5 seconds then present it. But when I do it now these errors come up ( added to code)

Comment: @rob mayor check again please

Comment: it's not longPress Error it's all about presentAlertController()

Comment: Your long press gesture working good. Error is about presenting  alertViewController

Comment: you gesture is working fine. I tried it now. that working would be of presentAlertController()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A long press gesture is a **continuous** gesture. That means that the recognizer will call your function (`myButton(_:)`) when it detects the start of the long press (after 0.5 seconds) with `state == .Began`, and repeatedly as the touch moves on the screen with `state == .Changed`, and once more when the gesture ends with `state == .Ended`. You're trying to present the alert on every `.Changed` call and on the `.Ended` call, and you get errors when you try to present an alert that's already being presented.

If you want to present the alert as soon as 0.5 seconds have elapsed, do it when the state is `.Began`, not when the state is anything **except** `.Began`.

```
@IBAction func myButton(longPress: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if longPress.state == .Began {
        presentAlertController()
    }
}
```

You only get one call with state `.Began`, so you won't try to present the alert again while it's already being presented.

Comment: @mayor This works but when I tap the button it also pops up. Even if I increase the time. Why is this happening?

Comment: You probably connected the button's action in the storyboard to the `myButton(_:)` function.

Comment: Also maybe you could start spelling my name correctly.

Comment: @ rob mayyoff sorry about the name misspelling i copied and pasted into this textfield. and you are correct! If I need my button connected to storyboard how would I go about doing that and using long press like this?

Comment: @JohnCarp I like how you misspelled Rob's name when you apologized for misspelling his name. :) (it seems you edited just after I posted this). FYI - Type the `@` symbol and then the first letter of the person's username. A tooltip will appear with one or more usernames. Hit the Tab key to select one for autocompleting the username.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for the tip. I didn't mean to misspell his name =]

Comment: If you want the button to do something different when tapped, you should make a separate `IBAction` for that.